# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/logout" after cloning directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logout, webpacker

I get this error message when I try to log out in my rails app:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/logout"
```

I have a route that directs to log out in my routes.rb
`delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'`
and I also have `destroy` in the sessions controller, which logs the user out by calling log out from the helper.

This was working perfectly fine until I recently cloned the repo onto another computer.
The thing I did to cause this change is probably cloning the directory and installing webpacker.
Here's what I have tried:
-`bundle`
-cloning again without installing web-packer (which threw an error that said `Webpacker can't find application.js`  and `Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Sessions#new` )

Can webpacker be responsible for logout not working? How can I properly install it? Can there be another problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried : `yarn install` and it worked.